# Weird iterator behaviour of Java HashSet

Tags: java, iterator, hashset

Today I ran into some weird behaviour with a HashSet's iterator. 
In the code example below, `idString` uses an object reference returned by `hs.iterator` to call the iterator's `next()` method.

In `idString2`the iterator is called via `hs.iterator()` and it does not work anymore.

So I assume that HashSet.iterator() returns a new iterator object each time it is called. But then, why can I still use `hs.iterator().hasNext()` in the while loop?

(Note that the code below is just an example :) )

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.junit.Test;

public class DummyTest {
  static final HashSet<Integer> TEST_DATA = new HashSet<Integer>(
    Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {
      1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
    }));

  @Test
  public void testRunTest() {
    // Correct output: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
    System.out.println(idString(TEST_DATA));
    // Only 1, 1, 1, 1, ...
    System.out.println(idString2(TEST_DATA));
  }

  static String idString(HashSet<Integer> hs) {
    Iterator<Integer> it = hs.iterator();
    String res = it.next() + "";
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      res += ", " + it.next();
      System.out.println(res); // debug
    }
    return res;
  }


  static String idString2(HashSet<Integer> hs) {
    Iterator<Integer> it = hs.iterator();
    // Prevent an infinite loop
    int i = 0;
    String res = null;
    res = it.next() + "";
    while (hs.iterator().hasNext() && i++ <= 10) {
      // if replacing hs.iterator() with 'it', it works
      res = res + ", " + hs.iterator().next();
      System.out.println(res); // debug
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each time you call `iterator()` it returns a *new* iterator, independent of any other iterators created before. So if you call `hs.iterator().next()` that will *always* give you the first element, and if you call `hs.iterator().hasNext()` on a non-empty collection, it will *always* return `true`.

Compare that with using `it` each time, which uses a single iterator throughout, therefore advancing the logical "cursor" each time you call `next()`.

Comment: But why does it still work if I only replace hs.iterator.next() by it.next(), but not hs.iterator.hasNext()? (You need to increase the limit in the  while loop, of course)

Comment: @user3001: It's not clear what you mean by "increase the limit" but in that case you'll be *printing* the right values, but your loop would never work. `hasNext()` doesn't change the state of the iterator - `next()` does.

Comment: @JonSkeet : Will this iterator returned by hashset maintain the same order of elements every time it is returned as long as the hashset is not modified ? or will it change on each call?

Comment: @sonic: I believe it will, but I would at least *try* not to rely on even that...

Answer (score 3):

This is not clearly documented in the Javadocs of the [iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator%28%29) method (be it in the [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator%28%29) or [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#iterator%28%29) interfaces) but all Java collections always return a new iterator under **iterator()** calls.

So, you should reuse the iterator you create instead of re-creating iterators on every loop run.

As an example, there is the **iterator()** implementation at **[AbstractList](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/AbstractList.java.html)**:

```
/**
* Returns an iterator over the elements in this list in proper sequence.
*
* <p>This implementation returns a straightforward implementation of the
* iterator interface, relying on the backing list's {@code size()},
* {@code get(int)}, and {@code remove(int)} methods.
*
* <p>Note that the iterator returned by this method will throw an
* {@link UnsupportedOperationException} in response to its
* {@code remove} method unless the list's {@code remove(int)} method is
* overridden.
*
* <p>This implementation can be made to throw runtime exceptions in the
* face of concurrent modification, as described in the specification
* for the (protected) {@link #modCount} field.
*
* @return an iterator over the elements in this list in proper sequence
*/
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new Itr();
}
```

Comment: That being said, I can't see any scenario why someone would even begin to think that calling iterator() multiple times would return the same exact object.

Comment: Since the documentation isn't really that good and the method isn't anything like **createIterator** or **newIterator** it's really hard to figure this out unless you try it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that `HashSet.iterator()` generates a *new* iterator on each call. The new iterator points always to the first element. Therefore you have to use the `it` iterator in the `idString2` method.

Answer (score 0):

It works because even though you are getting a new iterator instance and checking if there is a next element on the iterator, every single time the while checks the condition.

ex.
while (hs.iterator().hasNext() && i++ <= 10) {..

it will always return true cause it will always point to the first element, BUT you already assigned an instance of the iterator in this line:

Iterator it = hs.iterator();

So even though you are checking if there is a next element in every new iterator instance, you are getting the next element in the first iterator instance only assigned at the it variable.

The while loop ends because of the "&& i++ <= 10" condition, so it loops 10 times and then stops doing the while block.

If that condition wasn't there, you would get a NoSuchElementException when you tried to get the next non-existent element of the iterator.

The hasNext() only checks if there is a next element, while the next() makes the cursor point to the next element if it exists on the iterator object were its being called at.